# Apply a list of Functions to a Java stream's .map() method

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I map a stream of `NameValuePair`s with a `lookupFunction` (which returns a `Function`), like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> paramPairs = getParamPairs();
List<NameValuePair> newParamPairs = paramPairs.stream()
                .map((NameValuePair nvp) -> lookupFunction(nvp.getName()).apply(nvp))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(toList());
```

But what if `lookupFunction` returned a `Collection<Function>` instead, and I wanted to perform a `.map()` with each of the returned `Function`s.  How would I do that?

Comment: Note: you current code could be written: `stream.map(NameValuePair::getName).map(this::lookupFunction)...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `lookupFunction(nvp.getName())` returns a Collection of functions, you can get a Stream of that Collection and map each function to the result of applying it to the NameValuePair :

```
List<NameValuePair> newParamPairs = paramPairs.stream()
            .flatMap((NameValuePair nvp) -> lookupFunction(nvp.getName()).stream().map(func -> func.apply(nvp)))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems I still need that second                 .flatMap(Collection::stream)

Comment: @neu242 Why? Does each Function::apply return a Collection instead of a single value? That wasn't clear from the question, which is why I removed the `.flatMap(Collection::stream)`.

Comment: This would give you all permutations of applying the different functions to all members of the list. Say `lookupFunction` gives you 2 functions, and `paramPairs` has 3 items, then this will yield a list of 6 pairs. Not sure if that's what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a function that composes the Collections of functions into one function. And use that instead of lookupFunction in my code

```
Function<String, Function<NameValuePair, NameValuePair>> composedFun = 
     x -> lookupFunctions(x)
             .stream()
             .reduce((fun1, fun2) -> fun1.andThen(fun2))
             .orElse(y -> y);
...
  .map(nvp -> composedFun.apply(nvp.getName()).apply(nvp))
...
```